# meaning of phrase "get to pull"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm reading a story in English: it's not my native language. Two friends have fun together and make pancakes. Friends throw up pancakes in the air during cooking and have a contest: whose pancake will be higher.

> “This means I win.”
>
> “It does not! My pancake clearly went way higher than yours.”
>
> “It had to land back in the pan, Chris.”
>
> “Says who?”
>
> “Logic.”
>
> “Nu-uh, you don’t get to pull that -”
>
> “Well then get the damn thing off the ceiling fan then!”

I don't understand what does **you don’t get to pull that** mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand the context to get a meaning of this first.

1. One of the friends (Chris)' pancake got stick on the ceiling fan. That's the reason why he considered himself as the winner.
2. The other friend (unnamed) says it's againts the rules of their game.
3. Chris questiones his friend's judgement ("Says who?").
4. And the other friend gives a very general/wide answer by saying "Logic."
5. Since they haven't decided the rules of the game and there are no rules about sticking your pancake to the fan or the ceiling, Chris expresses himself by one sentence which might mean different things.

Now, there are possibilities but I will be explaining two.

- **Chris said "Nu-uh, you don’t get to pull that."**

**pull something:** *To carry out a deception or swindle: worried that his partners might be trying to pull something behind his back.*

Which means, "No, you can't do that to me."

- **Chris said "Nu-uh, you don’t get to pull that off."**

**pull off:** *To accomplish in spite of difficulties or obstacles; bring off: pulled off a last-minute victory.*

Which means, "No, you can't do that."

Basically, it depends on the context whether Chris' words are complete or incomplete due to flow of conversation.

Comment: The phrase `“Well then get the damn thing off the ceiling fan then!”` is the end of conversation. So what is option in this case?

Comment: @Heidel Chris' friend ends the conversation by saying that. Do we know Chris intended to say that or was he going to say more? I think the second explanation I gave is possibly the better of the two.

Comment: `Do we know Chris intended to say that or was he going to say more?` No, we don't. Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: @Heidel Glad to be helpful.

Comment: It is definitely the first option "to pull something", rather than "to pull something off". If it was the second option then Chris would have to say "You **didn't manage** to pull that off".

Comment: @AndyT At first, I thought of that. But then, the possibility of Chris' sentence being cut off by his friend made sense because first option sounds like something I wouldn't do to a friend. But you are not wrong.

Comment: @Apollo - Given the wording of your first definition, it does sound like something you wouldn't do to a friend, but I think that's just because of the wording chosen in your definition. In this particular situation, "to pull something" is very similar to "to get away with something".

Comment: @AndyT Maybe in friendly sense, that would be acceptable. Since this is a conversation between friends, I can say I agree.

Comment: @Heidel Please see above correspondence.

Comment: In my opinion, it's almost certainly the first meaning.  "You don't get to pull that off" doesn't really fit, because the other person is claiming that "logic" validates his reasoning, and for Chris to say "You don't get to achieve that" doesn't really make sense.  The other person is not achieving or accomplishing anything.